# How to remove background picture from an appendix?

Tags: pdfpages, watermark

in my tex document I have to use a watermark (that's for a degree thesis) so I use this code:

```
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(70,-40){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\includegraphics[width=5cm,keepaspectratio]{marca_agua}%
}}}
```

In the appendix I use `\includepdf` to include some datasheets and the watermark is there. So how can I remove it from the pdfs included in the appendix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `\ClearShipoutPicture`. It is a command from the `eso-pic` package. I think watermark uses it internally.